# $sort invalidates $skip in aggregation pipeline mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm using aggregation to query users. Each subsequent request uses $skip to get the next set of results as follows.

```
var aggPipeline = [
  locationMatch,
  userToUsersMatch,
  usersToUserMatch,
  {
    $skip:cursor
  },
  {
    $limit:perRequest
  } 
]
```

This works fine and returns users until there are none left to return. When I add a $sort into the pipeline the $skip seems to stop working and repeat data is returned in each subsequent request (even though the cursor/offset is incrementing).

```
aggPipeline = [
  locationMatch,
  userToUsersMatch,
  usersToUserMatch,
  {
    $sort:{lastActive:-1}
  },
  {
    $skip:cursor
  },
  {
    $limit:perRequest
  }
]
```

I'm attempting to sort all the results by the lastActive field and then return them, skipping the offset as to what has already been returned. I can't understand why $sort causes repeat data to be returned in subsequent calls - it is not always exact repeat from the previous request but may append a user every so often and remove the first user.

Anyone know what is happening here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is the result of Sequence Optimization, have a look, there is the example the same as yours ($sort + $skip + $limit Sequence):

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/